# How to use `IRepository` from `abp` in my own .net core project?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to use `IRepository` and `UOW` from `abp` library in my own .net core project, instead of generating the project from [Templates](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates).

Is there any detail description to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

this is for [Repository](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories)

and this is for [Unit of Work](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work) documentation

[aspnetboilerplate source code](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate)

[aspnetboilerplate  code samples](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples)